# Get IHost to release the port

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, port, asp.net-core-3.1

I am writing some integration tests.  In the integration tests I run a web server for each test.  They run fine, but sometimes the port that they need to run (it has to be the same one for each test) is not released.

This is how I am calling it:

```
IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args, baseUrl).Build();
var runTask = host.RunAsync(cancellationToken);

// Wait till the caller uses the cancellation token.
await runTask;

// This is called when the server is done hosting.
host.Dispose();
```

When each test is done, it calls:

```
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel(true);
```

And though I can verify that the host.Dispose() gets called, it does not seem to free the port when this happens.  It does get freed eventually, but it takes a long time.

**Is there a way to force the `host` to free the port that it is using?**